# Print the value of the first element that occurs N number of times

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm making this ReactJS application.

Part of a filtering system I have the following problem: 
Simplified...

I have an array, let's say its simple one like `let arr = [1,7,4,3,4,7];`
and I also input an N variable from the user that is a simple integer input.

I need to `return` or `console.log()` the integers from the array that is repeated N times. If there is nonsuch repeating number log err msg or return -1;

For instance,

`let arr = [1,7,4,3,4,7];` and `let n = 2;` i get `7`- cos 7 repeats 2 times

`let arr = [7,4,5,3,5,5,3,4,3,2,1];` and `let n = 3;` i get `5` - cos 5 repeats 3 times

`let arr = [1,6,4,6,4,6];` and `let n = 4;` i get `-1` or `cl("err")` - cos nothing repeats 4 times

Code from comments:

```
const getRepeatingNumber = (arr, n) => {
    for (unit of arr) {
        if (unit === maj_unit) count++;
        else {
            count--;
            if (count === 0) {
                maj_unit = unit;
                count = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return maj_unit;
}
```

Comment: ...and what have you tried?

Comment: `const getRepeatingNumber = (arr, n) => {
        for(unit of arr){
          if (unit === maj_unit)
            count++;
          else {
            count--;
            if(count === 0){
              maj_unit = unit;
              count = 1;
            }
          }
        }
        return maj_unit;
      }`

Comment: add code to the question please, not in comments. Thanks. Also explain the problem - what does the code, do, instead of what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#every`, create an accumulator and place the number as key and its frequency as value, once the value reaches the specified number of occurrence, break from the loop using `return false`, then return the result.

```js
const getRepeatingNumber = (arr, count) => { 
  let result = -1, hash = {};
  arr.every(n => {
    hash[n] = (hash[n] || 0) + 1;
    if(hash[n] === count) {
      result = n;
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }); 
  return result;
}
console.log(getRepeatingNumber([1,7,4,3,4,7],2));
console.log(getRepeatingNumber([7,4,5,3,5,5,3,4,3,2,1], 3));
console.log(getRepeatingNumber([1,6,4,6,4,6], 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which will fix your problem I hope.
You need to loop over all array values and find how many time each value occurred and save number of occurrence  in a result array because there may be multiple values occurred `n` number of times. i.e. in your provided array `let arr = [1,7,4,3,4,7];` 7 and 4 occurred twice but i am returning result[0] since you might only need first occurred value for `n` times.

```
let arr = [1,7,4,3,4,7];

let getRepeatingNumber = function (arr, n) {
 let result = [];
 arr.forEach((value) => {
   if (arr.filter(val => val === value).length === n && !result.includes(value)) {
     result.push(value);
   }
 });
 return result.length ? result[0] : -1
}

console.log(getRepeatingNumber(arr, 2)); // 7
```